Why does one-hot encoding introduce linear dependence among the columns?
In linear regression, we are told that one-hot encoding introduces linear dependence in the columns. This is because the $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n = 1$. This decreases the rank of the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ ("because there is linear dependence in the columns of $\mathbf{X}$") and hence the matrix $\mathbf{X^\top X}$ is not invertible. I don't understand why this is though.
Suppose we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    <\text{other features}> & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    ... & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    ... & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    ... & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    ... & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    ... & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Clearly, the columns (the last three) are linearly independent. There is no non-trivial way to get $(0, 0, \ldots, 0) ^ \top$. Is there something obvious I am missing?
I would appreciate it if someone could explain this to me. Thanks!

can you include the source?

Strictly speaking, it's an affine linear dependence since the sum of the one-hot features is the constant feature $\mathbf{1} = [1,1,1,\cdots,1]^\top$. This means that if you know all but one of the one-hot features, then you necessarily know the last one as well. These fail to be independent in the probabilistic sense, but the columns are in fact linearly independent, as you observe.

@SammyBlack So $(\mathbf{X^\top X})$ is still invertible and the linear model works as I expect it to, right?

Please explain what you call "one-hot" encoding : it isn't a widespread term...

You are right that with just one feature, and if you can guarantee that there is at least one occurrence in your data for each value in your categorical domain, you cannot get a singular design matrix. With more than one categorical features, however, this changes quite a lot.
Already with a few one-hot encoded vectors you increase the probability to introduce linear dependence, with this probability becoming a certainty once the total columns in the design matrix exceed the number of samples.
As a concrete example, consider two feature vectors $f_s$, $f_c$ corresponding to the sex and eye-color of a set of individuals, which for a sample obtain the values
$$f_s=(Male,Male,Male,Female,Female,Female,Male)^T\\
f_c=(Blue,Brown,Gray,Green,Green,Green,Blue)^T\,.$$
In the integer encoding, you would have
$$x_s=(1,1,1,2,2,2,1)^T\\
x_c=(1,2,3,4,4,4,1)^T\,$$
which are clearly not linearly dependent.
Now, with one-hot ncoding you would end up with a design matrix like
$$X=[F_s F_c],\quad \text{with }
F_s=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
1&0\\
1&0\\
0&1\\
0&1\\
0&1\\
1&0
\end{array}\right]\text{ and }
F_c=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right]\,.$$
In this encoding you end up having in your design matrix both the $2^\text{nd}$ column vector of $F_s$ and the $4^{\text{th}}$ of $F_c$, which are exactly the same.
